# On systemd-based systems how can I control mount options based on properties of the volume to be mounted?

Tags: automounting, systemd-mount

In particular I would like to be able to control umask/dmask based on properties such as the file system *type* being mounted.

Is there a way to control mount options based on the file system type with systemd?

*To clarify:* the point is *not* to *hardcode* certain [`x-systemd.*`-style options](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html) in `/etc/fstab` or so, but to provide system-global defaults on how systemd is supposed to deal with mounting volumes based on the volume properties (whereas the file system type is currently the one property I am most interested in).